# My KNN plot keeps creating parallel segments. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: machine-learning, python, cross-validation, data-visualization, k-nearest-neighbour

I am working on a project examining how counties recover following large storms. I suspect there is some degree of interaction in some of my variables, and want to use KNN to create a visual representation of this. For the purpose of fitting the KNN model and plotting the results, I created a five-level categorical variable from the recovery dependent variable, and fit a KNN model with each of the suspected independent variable pairings. That said, the results I keep getting look like a mess. For almost all of the models, the areas it creates are stripes or parallel lines. I have not been able to rule-out that my problems are the result of errors in my code--either in graphing or over-fitting. It is also probable that the relationship between the two independent variables and the dependent does not lend itself well to a KNN plot. I suspect getting parallel lines like these are the symptom of one or more cases of machine learning malpractice, but I am not practiced enough to figure out how.

I am open to all suggestions. I am considering using the same code to instead examine composite variable + single variable, or composite variable + composite variable. I am hoping that adding additional dimensionality will be enough to see the dv groupings pull apart.

(Sorry for the garish color choice, I was trying to keep the function flexible to the level of the dv)

```
# listIndices is a list of test/train masks for CV
def run_knn (dfY,dfX,listIndices,listParam=range(2,26)) :
    dictMSE = {}    # track param + MSE results for CV
    nFidelity = 1000 # graphing fidelity
    listNames = list(dfX) # get names of two IVs

    #   Begin CV
    #   Iter over param net
    for param in listParam : 
        listError = []
        
        #   Iter over train,test set
        for fold in listIndices :
            
            #   Fit model on train sets
            knnClass = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=param,
                                            weights='distance',
                                            ).fit(take(dfX,fold[0],axis=0),
                                                  take(dfY,fold[0],axis=0))
            
            #   Calculate error on test set. Save to list
            y_pred = knnClass.predict(take(dfX,fold[1],axis=0))
            listError.append(metrics.accuracy_score(take(dfY,fold[1],axis=0)
                                                    ,y_pred))
            
        #   end for fold
        #   Calculate, save MSE for param
        dictMSE[param] = mean(listError)

    #   end for param / end of CV
    #   Get best param from CV, 
    bestParam = min(dictMSE,key=dictMSE.get)
    bestMSE = dictMSE[bestParam]
    bestKNNClass = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=bestParam,
                                        weights='distance',
                                        ).fit(dfX,dfY) # Fit model with best params on full data
    
    # Begin graphing
    # First Column = X-axis  / Get left and right boundaries
    x_min,x_max = dfX[listNames[0]].min()*.95,dfX[listNames[0]].max()*1.05
    
    # Second Column = Y-axis  / Get top and bottom boundaries
    y_min,y_max = dfX[listNames[1]].min()*.95,dfX[listNames[1]].max()*1.05
    
    # Make grid
    xx,yy = meshgrid(arange(x_min,x_max,(x_max-x_min)/nFidelity),
                     arange(y_min,y_max,(y_max-y_min)/nFidelity)
                     )
    Zs = bestKNNClass.predict(c_[xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()]) # apply fit model to grid
    nColors = len(dfY.unique()) # get number of levels of DV, used to gen list of colors = # of levels
    
    # Make plot
    Zs = Zs.reshape(xx.shape)
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.contourf(xx,yy,Zs,
                 cmap=ListedColormap(sns.color_palette(None,nColors)))
    for i in range(nColors) :
        sns.scatterplot(x=dfX[listNames[0]][dfY==i+1],
                        y=dfX[listNames[1]][dfY==i+1],
                        palette=sns.color_palette(None,nColors)[i],
                        edgecolor='black')
    #   endfor
    fig.text(.1,.03,'K = '+str(bestParam))
    plt.title('Distribution of '+listNames[0]+' & '+listNames[1])
####
```

[image] [image]
[image]

Comment: look at the scale of your axes

Comment: @shimao , would that make a difference? Wouldn't lines be parallel, regardless of how much I stretched or re-centered them?

Comment: your lines aren't parallel, they just look like it. for your first plot -- suppose there were only two points: p1 = (0,0), and p2 = (1,1000), and you set $k=1$. now consider which point (0,1000) is closer to, and what the decision boundary would look like on your plot

Comment: I converted the IVs to standard normal before fitting the KNN and graphing. The x and y scales are now more or less equal. It looks like that fixed the problem--I understand now why it looked like parallel lines. The plots are still a mess, but that's because the structure of the data is a mess.